# Solving ODE with SciPy gives invalid value encountered in double_scalars error

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm trying to solve the Lane-Emden equation for arbitrary values of n (polytropic index). In order to use SciPy, I have represented the second-order ODE as a set of two coupled first-order ODEs. I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def poly(y,xi,n):  
    theta, phi = y  
    dydt = [phi/(xi**2), -(xi**2)*theta**n]  
    return dydt
```

Here, I defined phi = theta'

```
y0 = [1.,0.]  
xi = np.linspace(0., 16., 201)    
for n in range(0,11):  
    sol = odeint(poly, y0, xi, args=(n/2.,))  
    plt.plot(xi, sol[:, 0], label=str(n/2.))  
plt.legend(loc='best')  
plt.xlabel('xi')  
plt.grid()  
plt.show()
```

However, running this code results in the following error:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>   app.launch_new_instance()

At first, I thought this was a result of the singularity of the equation at xi = 0, so I changed my integration interval:

```
xi = np.linspace(1e-10, 16., 201)
```

This fixes the problem at n = 0., but not at other values of n. The plots I get don't make any sense and are just plain wrong.

Why do I get this error message, and how can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (which looks similar to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation)).  The derivative was written incorrectly (negative on the wrong element) and input to the derivative is changed simply to `n`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def poly(y,xi,n):  
    theta, phi = y  
    dydxi = [-phi/(xi**2), (xi**2)*theta**n]  
    return dydxi

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y0 = [1.,0.]  
xi = np.linspace(10e-4, 16., 201)

for n in range(6):
    sol = odeint(poly, y0, xi, args=(n,))
    ax.plot(xi, sol[:, 0])

ax.axhline(y = 0.0, linestyle = '--', color = 'k')
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([-0.5, 1.0])
ax.set_xlabel(r"$\xi$")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$\theta$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The original question used fractional values of the polytropic index, so something like follow could be used to investigate those values ...

```
for n in range(12):
    sol = odeint(poly, y0, xi, args=(n/2.,))

    if np.isnan(sol[:,1]).any():
        stopper = np.where(np.isnan(sol[:,1]))[0][0]
        ax.plot(xi[:stopper], sol[:stopper, 0])
    else:
        ax.plot(xi, sol[:, 0])
```

[image: fractional polytropic index values]

Comment: Thank you for replying! That's great, my code works now! Do you have any idea why it only works for integer values of n?

Comment: I think it doesn't like it when `theta` is less than or equal to zero.  If you look at the solution output it stops at `theta=0`.

Comment: That makes sense, because that would lead to complex solutions. Is there a way to use ODEint up until the point where theta<0?

Comment: Interesting.  I've edited my answer to plot the solution up until that point.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for all your useful ( and extremely quick) replies!!