# How to to solve Lane-Emden equation numerically in R using deSolve

Tags: r, ode

I want to use R to numerically solve a particular differential equation called the Lane-Emden equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation#Numerical_solutions

I am puzzled as to how to formulate the problem for the ODE solver in deSolve. I have some code and it gives an error that I don't understand and don't know how to fix.

I have tried to adapt examples from the book Solving Differential Equations in R, by K Soetart et al.

```
library(deSolve)
x <- seq(0,20,0.1)
n <- 1
y_ini <- c(phi=0, theta=1)

derivs <- function(x,y,parms){
  with(as.list(y),{
  dtheta <- -phi/(xi^2)
  dphi <- theta^n * xi^2
  list(c(dtheta,dphi))})
}

out <- ode(y=y_ini,times <- x,func = derivs,parms=NULL)
```

Error in eval(substitute(expr),data,enclos= parent.frame()) : object 'xi' not found Calls : ...
Func2 -> func -> with  -> with.default -> eval -> eval Execution halted

Comment: The error comes from the fact that your function involves an object `xi`, but you have not defined it anywhere.

Comment: The solution could be as easy as adding an `i` in `derivs <- function(xi,y,parms){`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/42404333/3088138 for a successful integration in python, and for the workarounds that were used.

Comment: "The error comes from the fact that your function involves an object xi, but you have not defined it anywhere."



Yes it does. That's why I think I have not formulted the problem correctly for deSolve. Looking at the problem definition in Wikipedia can you tell me how to reformulate it?

Comment: "The solution could be as easy as adding an i in derivs <- function(xi,y,parms){."



That generates the error

Error in ldoda(y,times, func, parms,...) :  illegal input detected before taking any input steps - see written message Calls : <Anonymous> ...withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> ode -> -> ldoda

Comment: This just means that the syntax check succeeded, all lines of the code could be parsed. Now you get to the real errors encountered during run-time checks on the arguments passed. The error message as cited is not very expressive towards the specific causes. // (Btw., if you do not pass parameters, leave this argument out, it already has a suitable default non-value.) // (Another btw.: The order of the returned derivatives does not match the order in the named pair `y_ini`.)

Comment: And you get a divide-by-zero situation in the first step, which might be what is detected and reported in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Performing all the changes that were mentioned in the comments:

- use `xi` in the parameter list of `derivs` instead of `x`,
- synchronize the order of `theta` and `phi` in state vector and derivative
- avoid dividing by zero by changing the first time to some small positive value

gives the code

```
library(deSolve)
x <- seq(0.0001,20,0.1)
n <- 1
y_ini <- c(theta=1, phi=0 )

derivs <- function(xi,y,parms){
  with(as.list(y),{
  dtheta <- -phi/(xi^2)
  dphi <- theta^n * xi^2
  list(c(dtheta,dphi))})
}

out <- ode(y=y_ini,times <- x,func = derivs,parms=NULL)
print(out)
theta <- out[,"theta"]
plot(times, theta)
```

which then produces the plot

[image: plot of solution]